# Fill an existing Excel file with data from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a bunch of rows and labeled columns.
I also have an excel file which I prepared with one sheet which contains no data but only
labeled columns in row 1 and each column is formatted as it should be: for example if I
expect percentages in one column then that column will automatically convert a raw number to percentage.

**What I want to do is fill the raw data from my DataFrame into that Excel sheet** in such a way
that row 1 remains intact so the column names remain. The data from the DataFrame should fill
the excel rows starting from row 2 and the pre-formatted columns should take care of converting
the raw numbers to their appropriate type, hence filling the data should not override the column format.

I tried using openpyxl but it ended up creating a new sheet and overriding everything.
Any help?

Comment: Got an example of your dataframe we can work with ?

Comment: If you want the richtext format, look into [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain about the order of columns is same, you can try this after opening the sheet with `openpyxl`:

```
df.to_excel(writer, startrow = 2,index = False, Header = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your # of columns and order is same then you may try `xlsxwriter` and also mention the sheet name to want to refresh: 
`df.to_excel('filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', sheet_name='sheetname', index=False)`